# Mysql Query sum of a column not displaying

Tags: php, mysql

Any idea why this isn't working? When i run it it doesn't display anything.

```
$qry = mysql_query(" SELECT SUM(payment_received) AS total FROM Orders ");
   {
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);
echo $row['total'];
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: check your php error_log.

Comment: what are the `{` and `}` there for?

Comment: Did you check if the query succeeded? `$qry = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());`. Never assume a query succeeds. They can succeed in exactly ONE way, and fail in a near infinite number of ways. Assume failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: you should not be using mysql_* functions in the first place, they have been deprecated for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct your code with the following example

```
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(payment_received) AS total FROM Orders");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)) {
{
    echo $row["total"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(payment_received) AS total FROM Orders") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
print_r($row);
```